# Асинхронный while без thread

Tags: c++

Есть функция

```
void Scroll::update(int x, int y, HWND hWnd, MSG* msg) {
if (msg->message == WM_LBUTTONDOWN ) {
        
        while (msg->message == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
        {
            doFunc();
        }
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        update(messageX, messageY,hwnd,&msg);
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
```

Как мне отследить, пока кнопка нажата? Поскольку я вхожу в цикл while, то сообщения перестают получаться

Comment: 1. Когда пользователь отпустит кнопку, прилетит сообщение `WM_LBUTTONUP`, его и надо отслеживать. 2. Чтобы обработка сообщений продолжалась, после каждой итерации своего цикла, вызывайте `GetMessage` с сопутствующей обработкой. Но лучше всё же работу вынести в отдельный поток.

Comment: @zed если использовать **GetMessage** в конце итерации, тогда последующие итерации не будут приходить

Comment: "**с сопутствующей обработкой**" всё можно сделать. Если подсказка не очень помогает, подождите, может кто-то напишет полноценный ответ.

Comment: Упс, в п.2 надо [PeekMessage использовать](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-messages-and-message-queues#examining-a-message-queue), а не Get...

Comment: @zed на данный момент все равно не понимаю, как это можно реализовать